# How to crop an image while taking it from the gallery and display it in an Image view

Tags: android, image, android-image

When I click on the button, It takes me to gallery to select an image, but it returns back to the activity without cropping, as soon as I select an image. Also the image is not displayed in the imageView.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button buttonCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_take_camera);
    Button buttonGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select_gallery);
    buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());

            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

            try {

                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }
    });
    buttonGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

            try {

                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
            imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }
    }

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
        if (extras2 != null) {
            Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");
            imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it returns back to the activity without cropping

That is because there is no requirement for any activity anywhere to honor those random `Intent` extras, let alone whatever activity the user chooses for your particular request (based on their device and installed `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activities). You will note that none of those extras are documented on `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Use one.

> Also the image is not displayed in the imageView.

That is because `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not return anything via a `data` `Intent` extra. Use the `Uri` that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` returns (obtained via `getData()` on the `Intent` passed into `onActivityResult()`). Provide that `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library (Picasso, Universal Image Loader, etc.).

Comment: Could you share any link where I can get the correct code for this ?